# Toggle UISwitch on/off in swift

Tags: swift, toggle, uiswitch

I'm having an issue toggling a UISwitch on/off.

When the switch labeled "blood glucose" is turned on, the switch below it, labeled "HbA1c" is turned off. And vice-versa. Flip "blood glucose" off, "HbA1c" is turned on. It works fine.

However, using the same code, the "HbA1c" UISwitch does not toggle its partner "blood glucose" on/off. I'm puzzled why the code works for one UISwitch but not the other.

The IBAction a1cSwitchPressed is connected properly, I stuck a label update in the function which worked.

[image: uiswitch toggle]

```
@IBAction func eagSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
 a1cSwitch.setOn(!sender.isOn, animated: true)     
}

@IBAction func a1cSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
 eagSwitch.setOn(!sender.isOn, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: checked if both of them connected to same switch in IB

Comment: Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of copy-paste the usual technique we always use to repeat the same item  , a IB connection to a UI component is copied also (`IBOutlet`,`IBAction`) which leads to unexpected results because it misses the connection to the actual item we thought it connected to